# Unable to capture and store response from postman API - python

Tags: python, api, postman

i am trying to capture response from postman, and it needs to be stored in csv.

This is the code i have tried, but not getting expected output

```py
UsergroupURL="https://"+ dex.3ds.com"
UsergroupsURL= UsergroupURL + "/3drdd/resources/b1/usersgroup?select=title,description,owner,members,pending_members,creation_date,modification_date&top=100&skip=0"

skip = 0
all_results = []

while True:
    usergroupresponse = session.post(UsergroupsURL, data = data)
    if usergroupresponse.status_code != 200:
        Failmsg="Failed to post usergroup. Status code : " + str(response.status_code)
        sys.exit(Failmsg)
    results = usergroupresponse.json()
    print(results)
    if len(results) == 0:
        # No more results to retrieve
        break
    # Append the results to the all_results list
    all_results += results
    # Increment skip to skip the previously retrieved results
    skip += 100
    # Update the URL with the new skip value
    UsergroupsURL = UsergroupURL + "/3drdd/resources/b1/usersgroup?select=title,description,owner,members,pending_members,creation_date,modification_date&top=100&skip=" + str(skip)
    print(results)
# Write the results to a CSV file
with open('response.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in all_results:
        writer.writerow(row.values())
```

in this code after  hitting URL first time  will get only 100 data ,but the URL contains multiples data so here  passing skip parameter to retrieve all data from URL, first 100 data to be captured to CSV file

am expecting  for when i try to hit URL on 2nd time the skip value should change to 100 so it will retrieves second 100 data 1st 100 will be skipped ,so second 100 data to be captured  CSV file, when i try to hit URL third time the skip value should change to 200 so it will retrieve rest of the data, it should be  hit until no response from URL

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code:

Need to change this part alone,

```
csv_filename = f"response_{skip_value}.csv"
with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    header = ["uri","title", "description", "owner", "members", "pending_members", "creation_date", "modification_date"]
    writer.writerow(header)
    for group in results['groups']:
        writer.writerow(group[x] for x in header)
        if not results:
            break            
# Increment the skip value by 100
skip_value += 100
```

Comment: You posted this as an answer, so now the site thinks your question has been answered, so fewer people will look at it...

Comment: @JohnGordon I have found the exact issue on my code, so updated the answer here